# Tableau Forecast reports

Tags: reporting, tableau-api, essbase

How to process Forecast reports in tableau from Multidimensional Data Source(Oracle Essbase) ?

I have a Time dimension consisting of Year,Month,Quarter and date.
I am trying to build a forecast report using year and Sales amount,but the forecast option is disabled in tableau.

On surfing a lot I found that, since the year is in dimension n not in valid date format, forecasting can not be done.

Is there any other option in tableau to achieve the forecast report using my time dimension ?

Or any calculated field option ?

looking for help or suggestions !!!

[image]

I could do the forecasting report using relational DB , excel ,text as source but couldnt do it using multidimensional data source. help pls ....!!!

Comment: could you show what _time_component_ look like: instead you can extract year OR change the data type to `Date` or `Date & Time`

Comment: @861051069712110711711710997114 : TIME_DIM is the time dimension i have used. I have four generations under TIME_DIM : year,Quarter,Month,Date. Also am not getting any option to change the data type either. how do i proceed ? any suggestions ?

Comment: sample data snapshot would help ! or post it as text !